# CSS width in Percent related to the grand parent

Tags: css, responsive-design, width, percentage

How to relate width in percent to the grand parent?

[image: CSS Responsive thumbnail slider]

Comment: Is the grandparent going to be full width of the page?

Comment: No that is not the case. I know how to work around if it was full with of the page, but no it is not. It has a dedicated width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply relate width of `li` s to the parent `ul` which in turn it relates to the grand parent `div`:

```
div{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
ul{
    width: 1000%;
}
li{
    width: 3%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript:

```
var g = document.getElementById('grandparent');
var w = g.clientWidth;
if (w > 400)
    w *= .3;
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
for (var i=0; i < c.length; i++) {
    c[i].style.width = w+'px';
}
```

I have [a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/26gu9s2j/).

Comment: thats not a matter of JS, as I did not tag the question using JS and tags & title say question is CSS. by the way thanks for your answer